# import and align data on worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

is there any way to import a closed worksheet in a workbook to a specific worksheet in my currently opened workbook and align the table headers? all i've been seeing are import to acces and import to powerpoint and i cant find import excel to excel. and I would choose the file by selection of the directory. how do i achieve this?

as of now, this is the code I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim Filter As String, Title As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Filename As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xls,"
    FilterIndex = 3
    Title = "Select a File to Open"
    ChDrive ("E")
    ChDir ("E:\excel")
    With Application
        Filename = .GetOpenFilename(Filter, FilterIndex, Title)
        ChDrive (Left(.DefaultFilePath, 1))
        ChDir (.DefaultFilePath)
    End With
    If Filename = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ImportMethod CStr(Filename)
End Sub

Sub ImportMethod(sFileName As String)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. When you say you want to import a worksheet. What do you want to do with the worksheet ? Copy and paste value/formats ? Only select a specific region on the worksheet ? Also when you say you want to "align the table headers". What do you mean ?

Comment: i'd want to copy and paste the value of the cells. the region of the worksheet varies. as for the "align the table headers" there are values on the tables headers right? so if there's date I'd want it to align to that, if there is quantity, I'd want it to align to that, if there's supplier I'd want it to align to that etc. . .

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726853/excel-vba-workbook-update/23730714#23730714) which might be of interest to you? This is how you create a connection to a closed workbook and in a specific worksheet. But this is for excel version 2007 and up. I haven't tried in lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened when I recorded importing a spreadsheet.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 19/05/2014 by AUser    '

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\AUser\Documents\Super.xls;Mode=Share Deny " _
        , _
        "Write;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet " _
        , _
        "OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;" _
        , _
        "Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy " _
        , _
        "Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False" _
        ), Destination:=Range("D10"))
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("Sheet1$")
        .Name = "Super"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .SourceDataFile = "C:\Users\AUser\Documents\Super.xls"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```